# Join onto custom postgres fuction in Sql Alchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a custom postgres function we'll call traversal that takes a list of ids and returns a set of children for them.

I'd like to be able to take an outer query and join onto the custom postgres function but I can't seem to figure out how to write that in Sql Alchemy. An example would be:

```
query = (
    session.query(
        traversal.child_ids
    ).select_from(
        some_table
    ).join(
        traversal(some_table.id)
    ).where(
        some_table.id.in_(list_of_ids)
    )
)
```

Is it possible to join onto a custom postgres function or do I need to turn it into a subquery or something?